# issue related to image fetching with CloudFlare

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, amazon-s3, aws-sdk, cloudflare

I uploaded my image by CDN (CloudFlare) to S3. Uploading is working fine with https but the issue is when I fetch the image with http or without then every time I get a previously cached image rather than a new image.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

> I uploaded my image by CDN (CloudFlare) to S3.

This sentence makes no sense at all. Uploading to S3 should have nothing to do with CloudFlare.

> when I fetch the image with http or without then every time I get a
>   previously cached image rather than a new image.

Because you haven't notified CloudFlare that the image has changed. You need to clear the CloudFlare cache. You can do this via the CloudFlare web interface or via the CloudFlare API.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to [purge your CloudFlare cache](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200169246-How-do-I-purge-my-cache-) to get the updated copy, in the caching tab of your CloudFlare dashboard there is an option to purge cache on individual files (or purge everything using the drop-down button).

[image: Purge CloudFlare Cache]

There is additional information on the CloudFlare support site: [How do I use CloudFlare with Amazon's S3 Service?](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200168926-How-do-I-use-CloudFlare-with-Amazon-s-S3-Service-)